# Format the result of one to many relations

Tags: sql

I have a table with

```
Data1
Data2
```

And an other one with

```
Data3
```

I have a one to many relation between my tables

My request is

```
Select * from tab1 left join tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.tab1-id
```

And the result is

```
Data1 | data2 | data3
Data1 | data2 | data3
```

And I'd like to have

```
Data1| data2 | data3, data3
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you ise? MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

There is no aggregate function to concatenate multiple strings from different rows of the same column in the SQL standard.

I guess this is one of the most urgently needed new functions in SQL.

So you'll have to go for macros, stored procedures or sth. like that.